# Accessing GUI from event handler

Tags: c#

When a byte from the serial port is received, it enters this handler correctly, but my label on the GUI does not change. **Edit**: Yes, it is in the same class as the GUI
**Edit 2** The function declaration does not need to be 'static'...I merely copy-pasted [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) from msdn
**edit 3** It works after getting rid of the static decleration and using something like [this](http://c-sharp-programming.blogspot.com/2008/07/cross-thread-operation-not-valid.html). 
Thanks for your help

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 gui = new Form1(); //main GUI

            try
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
                //gui.rxLabel.Text = indata;
                gui.txLabel.Text = "testttingg";
            }
            .......
```

Comment: Where is this event handler contained? In the `Form1` class?

Comment: yes, sorry for the absence of clarification.

Comment: @throwaway see my edit, you need to assign a reference of your form to the current instance.  In this case `this`.  In your case you are actually instantiating a new form instance, which is why you are seeing these results.

Comment: Thanks, I can't up vote you because of privileges, however.

Comment: @throwaway - i dont care about points as long as I helped out and it is working for you, that is more important to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you declaring a new instance of your form?  Just use your form's `txLabel`

In c#:

`this.txLabel.Text = "testing";`

In vb.net:

`Me.txLabel.Text = "testing"`

In the sample code you posted you are creating a new instance / reference to your actual form.  Use the existing instance, in addition, use `this` rather then a new instance.

I had to edit my question as I noticed you were using a static method.

Try this:

```
 public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f = (Form1) sender;

            f.textBox1.Text = "testing";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataReceivedHandler(this, null);     
        }
```

Of course I am just calling `DataReceivedHandler()` from a button event, you can call it from your own event.  Point being is you need to pass the current instance, `this` to the function.  Once inside the function do not create a new instance of the form, just set a reference to the current form and use that reference to apply the settings to the property (txtBox or Label or whatever).

Comment: Static methods can't use instance variables like that

Comment: @HandsomeCam - I just noticed that.  Need more info from op on how this is being done...

Comment: @HandsomeCam - I gave him a sample of how he could use the current instance inside of a static function.  In my case I'm using the click event of a button, in his case he needs to use the appropriate event and pass `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're instantiating a new instance of Form1, instead of accessing the existing form in memory.